# How to group/summarize table in Power BI based on criteria

Tags: powerbi, dax, grouping, powerquery, transformation

I have been struggling with a problem for quite a while now. I have mainly been using Excel to go around this every time but I'm sure it can be done and automated in Power BI which is what I need help with. I will highlight my problem and step by step process I do to achieve my desired result and hopefully someone can help translate this to Power BI.

```
Name    Segment1    Segment2        AccountID
Apple   Technology  Entertainment   ABCD
Apple   Technology  Entertainment   ABCD
Apple   Telecom     Services        PWRK
Banana  Banking     Finance         LITE
Banana  Banking     Finance         LITE
Banana  Banking     Finance         LITE
Banana  Banking     Services        ITER
Zebra   Energy                      TRWD
Zebra   E-commerce                  WERD
Zebra   Services                    AWED
Qwerty                              TRUC
Qwerty  Services    Telecom         TYRE
Qwerty  Trade                       MIGS
```

Image 1 is what my starting table looks like. The objective is to return only 1 row per 'Name'. First rule should be the Name, Segment 1, Segment 2 with the max number of 'Account ID' under it. The second is if incase there's a tie, we should get any or the row with non blank Segment 1 and Segment 2 (whatever is easier).

```
Name    Segment1    Segment2        Count of Account ID
Apple   Technology  Entertainment   2
Apple   Telecom     Services        1
Banana  Banking     Finance         2
Banana  Banking     Services        1
Zebra   Energy                      1
Zebra   E-commerce                  1
Zebra   Services                    1
Qwerty                              1
Qwerty  Services    Telecom         1
Qwerty  Trade                       1
```

In the second step I take a count of each Account under said Name, Segment 1, Segment 2.

```
Name    Max of Count
Apple   2
Banana  2
Zebra   1
Qwerty  1
```

In the third step, I take max of count of Account under said Name.

```
Name    Max of Count of Account ID  Segment1    Segment2
Apple   2                           Technolohgy Entertainment
Banana  2                           Banking     Finance
Zebra   1                           Energy      
Qwerty  1                           Services    Telecom
```

This is the final desired output. Continuing from the third step, I applied a lookup on 'Name & Max of Acc ID' (Create a new ID column) against Image 2 (where I also create 'Name & Max of Acc ID' field, and return Segment 1 and Segment 2. The only manual adjustment I have made here is input Segment 1 and Segment 2 for 'Qwerty' as it had a tie on all 3 segments and I wanted the non blank ones. If this is too difficult, I am fine with returning first match or whatever here.

Would be grateful if someone can help out!

I have tried solving this problem using a DAX measure or Power Query but my Power BI skills are nowhere like my Excel skills. I managed to make some progress but still getting stuck midway.

Comment: Have you looked at GROUP BY ?  (Edit query, (takes you to editor, then click the Group By button.